# Thread synchronization issue in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

In my app I need to estalish an Http Connection with a web server, the http connection is established when user select a ListField element. It works properly, I wrote a method to establish http connection and it returns a result and my program process these data.

But it hangs the UI since the method I wrote not in a seperate thread (the method I wrote to establish http connection is in a singleton class). Now I change my method in a seperate thread, now I got illegal Thread State exception.

So I changed my class (HttpConnection class-now its not singleton),now there is no illegal state exception, but I don't get the result as I desired.

I have less experience in java and blackberry, I don't know how to synchronize two threads. So I introduce a static variable 'i' at when program enters to the thread it become 0 and when it got http response it changed to 1.

So in waits my program using a while loop and check the i value. When it become 1, I receive the http response (which is also a static string variable). But now also my program hangs indefinitely, I know this is not a good method.

Please help to over come the problem by sharing your ideas about thread synchronization, links codes etc.

its my run method:

```
public void run() {
    i =0;
    observerStatusUpdate(i, "Please Wait");
    StreamConnection streamConnection=null;
    InputStream inputStream=null;
    HttpConnection httpConnection = null;
    String result="";
    try {
        streamConnection=(StreamConnection)Connector.open(url);
        httpConnection=(HttpConnection)streamConnection;
        httpConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
        //httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "//json");
        int httpStatus=httpConnection.getResponseCode();
        if(httpStatus==HttpConnection.HTTP_OK){
            inputStream = streamConnection.openInputStream();
            //byte[] radioTimeData=new byte[8000];
            byte radioTimedataByte;                 
            while((radioTimedataByte=(byte)inputStream.read())!=-1){
                result=result+(char)radioTimedataByte;
            }

            httpres = result;   
            setResult(result);
            i=1;

            observerStatusUpdate(i, "");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {   
        i=1;
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Dialog.alert("No Internet Connectivity");   
                //System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

And its called using another class like

```
grabAPIFactory.setUrl(newUrl,o1);           
grabAPIFactory.start();
grabAPIFactory.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
while(GrabapiFactory.i==0){
    Thread.sleep();
}
string httpresult = GrabapiFactory.httpres;// static variale getting result from server
// process the httpresult here.....
```

Comment: Paragraphs, and some code illustrating your problem may help.

Comment: Without seeing the relevant parts of your code, we can only guess what the problem is.

Comment: since my code is lengthy ,I did not add it,Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description it sounds like you should reconsider your app architecture. I believe those sigletons/waiting loops are hacky/ugly ways to do what you need.

Basically all what you need to know is: when being on a non-UI thread you need to make smth on a UI-thread, then a common pattern on BB is to use one of the following methods:

- [Application.invokeLater(Runnable runnable)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)
- [Application.invokeAndWait(Runnable runnable)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

So upon user event (a click) you start a new `Thread` which does networking (or some other potentially long-running actions) and when you need to update the UI (e.g. push/pop a `Screen`, change appearance on a `Field`) then you use `Application.invokeLater(Runnable runnable)`.

Also check [BB User Interface Overview](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/UI-summary.html) and [BlackBerry UI Threading - The Very Basics](http://www.thinkingblackberry.com/archives/182).